# Как лучше подключить несколько файлов css?

Tags: css

У меня есть четыре файла css: style.css, normalize.css, fonts.css и media.css. Как лучше подключить их в моей верстке? Через несколько link или через @import в главный файл css?

Comment: через линк.....

Comment: Абсолютно по-барабану. Дело исключительно вкуса. Если вы проектируете свой wordpress с блекжеком, то может быть лучше спроектировать объединение css заранее. А если, например, вы подгружаете css-код из компонентов хуками, то объединение вам встанет бесполезным ненужным головняком на многие месяцы проектирования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Несколько `link` лучше, чем `@import` поскольку позволяют грузить файлы одновременно и с того момента, как их обнаружил парсер html.

В принципе, можно объединить все стили в один файл, но я бы рекомендовал поделить хотя бы на два - один со стилями, которые почти никогда не меняются (нормализация, шрифты, библиотеки), второй - с обычными стилями (можно тоже разделить на два - общие стили и стили для конкретной страницы). Кстати, со скриптами можно поступить аналогично.

Answer (score 3):

Импортируйте все CSS (или SCSS/SASS) файлы в один CSS файл а дальше минифицуруйте его.
На этапе разработки для вашего-же удобства лучше всего иметь отдельно всё.
Стили шрифтов в отдельном файле (у меня это fonts.scss) и так далее.
А на этапе сборки всё объединяем и как выше писал уже.